# How to make static library in makefile

Tags: unix, makefile, static-libraries

I have the following makefile so far right now...

```
# Beginning of Makefile

OBJS = obj/shutil.o obj/parser.o obj/sshell.o
HEADER_FILES = include/shell.h include/parser.h
STATLIB = lib/libparser.a lib/libshell.a
EXECUTABLE = sshell
CFLAGS = -Wall
CC = gcc
# End of configuration options

#What needs to be built to make all files and dependencies
all: $(EXECUTABLE) $(STATLIB)

#Create the main executable
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJS)
        $(CC) -o $(EXECUTABLE) $(OBJS)

$(STATLIB): $(
#Recursively build object files
obj/%.o: src/%.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I./include  -c -o $@ $<


#Define dependencies for objects based on header files
#We are overly conservative here, parser.o should depend on parser.h only
$(OBJS) : $(HEADER_FILES)

clean:
        -rm -f $(EXECUTABLE) obj/*.o
        -rm -f lib/*.a

run: $(EXECUTABLE)
        ./$(EXECUTABLE)

tarball:
        -rm -f $(EXECUTABLE) *.o
        (cd .. ; tar czf Your_Name_a1.tar.z shell )

# End of Makefile
```

I am trying to generate static libraries libparser.a and libshell.a

I have no idea how to create these static libraries...

Comment: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/gcc/create_lib.html

Answer (score 9):

You create static libraries with the `ar` command:

```
lib/libparser.a: $(OBJECT_FILES_FOR_LIBPARSER)
        ar rcs $@ $^

lib/libshell.a: $(OBJECT_FILES_FOR_LIBSHELL)
        ar rcs $@ $^
```

If your `ar` command doesn't understand the `s` option, you'll have to run `ranlib` on the `.a` file produced by `ar` as well. In that case, replace `ar rcs $@ $^` with `ar rc $@ $^ && ranlib $@`.

Comment: doesn't it suppose to be `-rcs` instead of just `rcs`?